# Requiring a PIN to login with Symfony2

Tags: php, user-interface, authentication, symfony

I am trying to create a login system inside Symfony2 that requires both a Username/Password and a PIN. This means that when the user presses the login submit button Symfony2 should check against the username, password and the pin.

I don't really know where to start. I have a valid login system working with just a username/password using the UserInterface.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You could start from reading [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) ;)

Comment: That did the trick! Was eventually able to work it out from that tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Follow this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) In the listener catch the error with a RedirectResponse to your login page and set a session variable with:

```
$session->set(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, array('message' => 'The details entered are invalid'));
```